# How to upload large size of file by using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, api, afnetworking

I'm working on an app in which I need to upload file to some server, and I'm using `AFNetworking` to upload file.

All work fine except if file size is short like 2mb and if more than this, server respond me error with status code 500 and doesn't upload file.

Here below is code how I am uploading.

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:lang forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];
[request setValue:authVal forHTTPHeaderField:@"authorization"];
[request setValue:[headerParams objectForKey:@"x-file-name"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-file-name"];
[request setValue:[headerParams objectForKey:@"x-convert-document"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-convert-document"];
[request setValue:[headerParams objectForKey:@"x-source"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-source"];

//convert parameters in to json data

if ([params isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                         error:&error];
    jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:action]];
[request setTimeoutInterval:200.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:imageData];
NSLog(@"File size is : %.2f MB",(float)imageData.length/1024.0f/1024.0f);


AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];

operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSInteger statusCode = [operation.response statusCode];
    NSNumber *statusObject = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:statusCode];
    successBlock(responseObject, statusObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
```

}

The line of code `[request setHTTPBody:imageData];` is setting `NSData` of image.

The same thing works on Android and its working fine but they'r using stream, first to write file into Physical path then by using stream to upload. Is this possible by using `AFNetworking`? or can I achieve this by using other approach too?

Looking for Suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: use multiform data for your concept

Comment: Also check if server has limitation. If max upload size is set on server.

Comment: @AshishP. No there is no limit, as I mentioned Android guys doing same large file by using stream

Comment: As in documention of API this mentioned, "Content–Type application/octet-stream" for stream

Comment: There IS something wrong with your server, nevermind the poor Android guys. There is 500 you say? Internal __server__ error?

Comment: Does the actual HTTP message meet the criteria of the server?

Comment: I am getting message "An internal system error occurred - please report this issue to *****" with status code 500

Comment: Server guy saying that you've to use stream for uploading file.

Answer (score 0):

Note :- I have just implemented Image Upload service using AFNetworking 3.0,

-> Here kBaseURL means Base URL of server

->serviceName means Name of Service.

->dictParams means give parameters if needed, otherwise nil.

->image means pass your image.

Note :- This code written in NSObject Class and we have apply in our Project.

```
+ (void)requestPostUrlWithImage: (NSString *)serviceName parameters:(NSDictionary *)dictParams image:(UIImage *)image success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *responce))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

NSString *strService = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kBaseURL,serviceName];
[SVProgressHUD show];

NSData *fileData = image?UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5):nil;

NSError *error;
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:strService parameters:dictParams constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

if(fileData){
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:fileData
                                name:@"image"
                            fileName:@"img.jpeg"
                            mimeType:@"multipart/form-data"];
}
} error:&error];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

NSLog(@"Wrote %f", uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);
}
                              completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *    _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                  [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                                  if (error)
                                  {
                                      failure(error);
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                      NSLog(@"POST Response  :      %@",responseObject);
                                      success(responseObject);

                                  }
                              }];

[uploadTask resume];

}
```

--> Now apply in our project.

```
UIImage *imgProfile = //Pass your image.        


[WebService requestPostUrlWithImage:@"saveImageWithData" parameters:nil image:imgProfile success:^(NSDictionary *responce) {

    NSString  *check = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[responce objectForKey:@"status"]];
    if ([check  isEqualToString: @"1"]) {
       //Image Uploaded. 
    }
    else
    {
     //Failed to Upload.
    }


} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    //Error
}];
```